# Styling RadioButton using XML drawable

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change RadioButton's indicator using a simple shape state selector. I've created the following XML named moon_radio.xml and placed it to a `drawable` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/moon_light_plate" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/moon_light_plate" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/moon_light_plate_pressed" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/moon_light_plate_pressed" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Then I specify `android:button="@drawable/moon_radio"` property on a RadioButton in my layout. This does not work for some reason. What's wrong?

*** EDIT ***
May be I've explained unclear, but *I do not want* change background, I want to change indicator, i.e. default dot.

This is what I get:

[image]

And This is what I want to get"

[image]

Comment: add you layout code,and do mention,what kind of difficulty or weird behaviour you are facing!

Answer (score 2):

You should specify this in `android:button` property of `RadioButton` is correct you just need to add `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `RadioButton` like below-

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/moon_radio"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="RadioButton1" />
```

Setting your radioButton background will serve your purpose if you set `android:button="@android:color/transparent"`.

Comment: No.  That makes the button transparent always.  You want an item-state drawable for the button attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To see what the default RadioButton uses, based on the apps theme, go into the source code for one of the APIs.  For example, from the SDK Manager you can install the "Sources for Android SDK" for API 18.  It will get placed in:

```
sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\drawable\
```

Find the **btn_radio.xml**, **btn_radio_holo_dark.xml**, and **btn_radio_holo_light.xml** files.  They have state-selectors for the different states, and you can see what png files they use.

You can find those png files in the drawable-mdpi\ directory to see what they look like (like **btn_radio_on.png**).

Then you can copy the btn_radio.xml file to your drawable directory and make it use your images (or drawable shapes) for the different states.

Looking at one of those files, I think your states are wrong (like checked=true pressed=false).  I don't see that in the default file , except for the last one that just has checked=true.  It goes through the selectors from top to bottom.  So, it only gets to the bottom one if the ones above it aren't selected.

And, you put your selector drawable in the android:button attribute.